# Groovy: How to get statically inferred return type from AST

Tags: java, groovy, type-systems, static-compilation

I'm using Groovy to allow users to script and customize certain parts of my Java application. I am using static compilation of all user-provided scripts.

My question is: if my code expects to receive e.g. a value of type boolean as the result of the user script, is there any way for me to check whether or not the provided user script will always return a boolean without actually executing the script? In other words, how can I access the results of the type inference performed by the static groovy compiler? I would like to be able to tell the user "hey, your script does not always return a boolean" while they are editing the script content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no straight-forward way, but it's possible. Boolean is especially hard as the compiler will happily apply all sorts of type-coersions (e.g. transform an int to boolean without complaining). I've had the exact same problem and did the following steps:

1. <s>ASTTransformation to set the return type to boolean</s> (not required, was an artifact of a half-working earlier iteration)
2. ASTTransformation to meterialize all return statements
3. TypeCheckingExtension to visit the ReturnStatements and verify they are of type boolean
4. ASTTransformation to perform static type transformation with the TypeCheckingExtension

For 1:

Extend `ClassCodeVisitorSupport`, in `visitMethod` identify all methods you want to return boolean (e.g. check for matching naming conventions)

Set the `returnType` of the `MethodNode` to `ClassHelper.boolean_TYPE`

For 2:

For the same methods as above call `org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.ReturnAdder.visitMethod`

For 3:

Extend `AbstractTypeCheckingExtension`, override `afterVisitMethod`. At this point the `AbstractTypeCheckingExtension` will have inferred the lower bound of all expressions inside the method. Use a `ClassCodeVisitorSupport` subclass and override `visitReturnStatement`. Use `getType(statement.expression)` to get the inferred type. Note that this can be different from `statement.expression.type` (the type according to the AST). Call `addStaticTypeError` on non boolean type.

For 4:

Extend `StaticTypesTransformation`
Override `newVisitor` and create a new `StaticTypeCheckingVisitor` and call `addTypeCheckingExtension` on it to add your `TypeCheckingExtension`

## GitHub Project

https://github.com/MeneDev/groovy-dsl-building-blocks-enforce-return-type

It may even be reusable as a dependency ;)

Comment: Thank you for the very elaborated response! I will try to implement your approach. Having this example on github would definitly be helpful. Alas, there is very little information on these aspects of Groovy to be found online.

Comment: Included quite some trial and error. I'll do my best!

Comment: There you go: https://github.com/MeneDev/groovy-dsl-building-blocks-enforce-return-type

Answer (score 0):

Not with "Typical" groovy--it's the difference between groovy's runtime typing and java's compile-time static typing.

For instance, is the following method going to return a Boolean?

```
def value(v) {
    return v;
}
```

In version 2.0, however, there IS a @CompileStatic annotation that I think would force all types to be know at compile time.  Not sure how you would force this "On" for your client's script code though.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what we do. You can add the static compilation as an AST Customizer, that works nicely. The problem that we are facing is how to access the results of the analysis, i.e. the type-annotated AST.

Comment: Could you require the user to implement a specific interface with his code?  That should fail to compile if he wasn't returning a boolean...  If the user code is more of a "Script", you might be able to force his script to implement an interface before compiling it for him.

Comment: Letting users implement an interface on their own is definitly too much to ask (syntactically). One option would be to wrap a method signature around the user code before compiling it. However, the user loses the ability to define helper functions in the script, because methods cannot be nested in Groovy AFAIK. An AST transform is less hacky than string concatenation but might get the job done as well. The cleanest option would still be to leave the script as-is and analyze the AST. The problem is that I don't know how to do that in the Groovy compiler API.